# How to distort an image using perlin noise?

Tags: unity, c#, perlin-noise, image-processing

I'm trying to generate a 2D map and currently I'm doing so by the use of voronoi diagram. The problem I found is that all biomes have really hard edges and I would like to smooth them out a bit.

[image]

Initially I was thinking smoothing out voronoi curves, which appears to be far more complex as I imagined. Then I thought about perlin distorion, which seems far more doable. Although, I'm not sure what is the best way to implement this.

This is the function I use to generate a voronoi diagram:

```
void Generate()
{
    Vector2Int[] centroids = new Vector2Int[regions.Length];
    Color[] regColors = new Color[regions.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < regions.Length; i++)
    {
        centroids[i] = new Vector2Int(Rand.Range(0, map), Rand.Range(0, map));
        regColors[i] = regions[i].color;
    }
    Color[] colors = new Color[map * map];
    for (int x = 0; x < map; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < map; y++)
        {
            int index = x * map + y;
            colors[index] = regColors[GetClosestCentroidIndex(new Vector2Int(x, y), centroids)];
        }
    }
}
int GetClosestCentroidIndex(Vector2Int pixelPos, Vector2Int[] centroids)
{
    float smallestDst = float.MaxValue;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < centroids.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(pixelPos, centroids[i]) < smallestDst)
        {
            smallestDst = Vector2.Distance(pixelPos, centroids[i]);
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

While doing some research I stumbled upon this website, which shows the exact result I'm trying to achieve:
https://observablehq.com/@kerryrodden/image-distortion-with-perlin-noise

Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you

[**Solved**]

By the help of the user DMGregory, the map is now looking much better!
This is the new voronoi diagram, after the distortion had been applied.

[image]

Currently, I'm using these settings, but I will probably tweak them later.
**Scale**: *10*
**Octave Count**: *1*
**Amplitude**: *4*
**Lacunarity**: *1*
**Persistence**: *1*
And for the seed, currently, I'm using just a randomly generated seed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, give yourself a 2D turbulence function with parameters you can adjust to shape the noise the way you want:

```
public float baseScale = 50.0f;
public int octaveCount = 4;
public float amplitude = 5.0f;
public float lacunarity = 2.0f;
public float persistence = 0.5f;

// Arbitrary numbers to break up visible correlation between octaves / x & y
public Vector2 seed = new Vector2(-71, 37); 

Vector2 Get2DTurbulence(Vector2 input) {

    input = input/baseScale + seed;
    float a = 2f * amplitude;

    Vector2 noise = Vector2.zero;

    for(int octave = 0; octave < octaveCount; octave++) {
        noise.x += a * (Mathf.PerlinNoise(input.x, input.y) - 0.5f);
        noise.y += a * (Mathf.PerlinNoise(input.x + seed.y, input.y + seed.y) - 0.5f);
        input = input * lacunarity + seed;
        a *= persistence;
    }

    return noise
}
```

Then add turbulence to your position before you use it to find the closest centroid:

```
int GetClosestCentroidIndex(Vector2Int pixelPos, Vector2Int[] centroids)
{
    Vector2 warpedPos = pixelPos + Get2DTurbulence(pixelPos);

    float smallestDst = float.MaxValue;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < centroids.Length; i++)
    {
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(warped, centroids[i]);
        if (distance < smallestDst)
        {
            smallestDst = distance;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you :)

Comment: I'd love to see an image of your result, if you'd like to edit it into this answer. :) Sharing the parameter values you used could help future users too — I just guessed at these ones without running the code. ;)

Comment: Of course! I added a small update of the final result :) The map is not looking too interesting at the moment, but that's because more biomes will be added. But the shape of the regions is now looking much better!

Comment: Nicely done! You might also be interested in the notion of the [Worley noise basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worley_noise), where you use not just the identity of the closest noise point, but also the distance to the closest noise point, or distance to the second-closest, or difference between closest & 2nd-closest distances etc. This can help you generate internal structure in your cells, or cross-fade near the border regions. [More on the relationships between these noise bases and cool stuff you can do with them here](https://thebookofshaders.com/12/)

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the link to the website! I was thinking about this, how can I recognize the borders of the regions. When the map is generated I will then create props and doodads on each cell and would like to also create mountains or trees surround each region. To kind of separate them better. I will try to read through this website and hopefully figure out the best way in doing this. Cause at the moment the only way I can think of is to look around each cell and if the neighbor cell belongs to the other type of region, create a separator, which is either a tree or a mountain.

Comment: Worley F2 - F1 noise may be useful here then. It takes a value of zero at the borders between cells, so you can use that as an input to your divider generator.